# Sitecore WeBlog Comment moderation enabled, but comments are posted before approval

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2, weblog

I have enabled comments moderation by following the instructions in the [documentation](https://github.com/WeTeam/WeBlog/wiki/Comment-Workflow). When posting comments, I am able to see them in the Workbox under Approval needed but they are still posted to the blog right away before being approved. Am I missing some configuration?

Comment: Please add a comment if you are going to down vote.

Comment: It seems as if there is a rash of downvotes across the Sitecore posts. I've reached out on Meta to see if there is a way to report it.

Comment: Just a hint for possible close voters: SiteCore is a high-end CMS and these type of questions can only be asked by or are useful for developers, not for normal users. Migration to Superuser.com is not correct. See also [this MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291566/how-to-report-invalid-downvotes)

Comment: @rene It's "Sitecore", not SiteCore :)

Comment: @jammykam fine with me... I'll try remember next time

Answer (score 2):

In the `Workflow` of the Blog Comments is the Approval `state` marked as `Final`, i.e. the Final checkbox is ticked? It is located on the Workflow State Item.

[image]

This indicates to Sitecore that the Item is in the final workflow state and can be published. Therefore appearing on the blog before they have been approved (providing it has been published).

It's also worth checking when the comments are being published, if they are automatically published when submitted by the user.

Comment: The final checkbox is checked in the Approved state. Should I uncheck it? I tried unchecking but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: That's the source of your issue then. If it is checked the comment is then in a publishable state. Therefore uncheck it, publish the workflow state then after that add a comment to the blog. 
This change won't retroactively go through and unpublish existing comments in approved state however, best recommendation is to manually remove them from the web database or republish with sub-items the folder containing all the comments. Give the first part a try first

Comment: Rereading your comment, what is the Workflow state the blog comments are first created in? Does this have the Final checkbox checked?